Calculation of canonical partition function for fermion system with degenerate energy levels
I'm having trouble in visualising the generalized version of the question asked here.
We have a system with levels whose energies are $0, \epsilon, 2 \epsilon, ..., n\epsilon$, and the number of levels of each listed energy is correspondingly $g_0,g_1,..., g_n$.
Now, let us say that we have N particles that follow Fermi-Dirac statistics, $N< \sum_i ^n g_i$. For our purposes this simply means that no two particles can occupy the same energy state.
How do we determine the canonical partition function then? For Bose statistics it is straightforward since we only need to take all possible combinations, which gives us: $\mathbb{Z}=(\sum_i ^n g_i e^{-\beta \epsilon})^N$
It seems much more complicated for the concerned case however, since not only is it necessary to exclude cases where all particles are in the same energy level, but also those where only some are.

See this for the discussion of the bosonic case -- it contains also references discussing the fermionic case. Some references in my answer here might be useful too.

You have two nice answers. Please read this and take appropriate actions. If you feel that none of the answers is addressing your problem, consider to leave a comment below the posts or edit the question. This also holds for all of your other questions.

@TobiasFünke Oh sure, I was caught up in some work and didn't have much time to go through them.

In general it is easier to compute the canonical partition function from the grand canonical one. For a direct computation of the canonical ensemble, it is also easier to think in terms of orbitals rather than energies with degeneracies.
For $N$ fermions, if $k$ ranging from $1$ to $K=\sum_{i=1}^n g_i$ is the index of the orbital with corresponding energy $\epsilon_k$ (not necessarily distinct), the canonical partition function is:
$$
Z_N = \sum_{(N_k)\in\{0,1\}^K,\sum_{k=1}^K N_k = N}\exp\left(-\beta\sum_{k=0}^KN_k\epsilon_k\right)
$$
If you want to think in terms of distinct energies and degeneracies, you can adapt the previous formula. I'll write $g_\epsilon$ the $\epsilon\in\mathcal E$ energy level, then:
$$
Z_N = \sum_{N_\epsilon\leq g_\epsilon,\sum_{\epsilon\in\mathcal E} N_\epsilon = N}\frac{N!}{\prod_{\epsilon\in\mathcal E}N_\epsilon!}\exp\left(-\beta\sum_{\epsilon\in\mathcal E}N_\epsilon\epsilon\right)
$$
In either case, it is easier to instead consider the grandcanonical partition function:
$$
\mathcal Z = \sum_{N=0}^\infty Z_Nz^N
$$
with $z$ the fugacity. Mathematically, this is basically a $z$ transform, and allows you to go back and forth from the two formulation. The grandcanonical ensemble has the advantage of having an explicit partition function that factorises:
$$
\mathcal Z = \prod_{k=1}^K(1+ze^{-\beta \epsilon_k})
$$
or equivalently in terms of degeneracies:
$$
\mathcal Z = \prod_{\epsilon\in\mathcal E}(1+ze^{-\beta \epsilon})^{g_\epsilon}
$$
You can then recover $Z_N$ from $\mathcal Z$ by Taylor expansion and taking the $N$-th monomial. Typically, if you have a simple analytic expression for $\mathcal Z$, it could also be judicious to use contour integration like:
$$
Z_N = \frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\mathcal Z\frac{dz}{z^{N+1}}
$$
with $C$ a sufficiently small contour about the origin so as not to enclose any poles/branch points of $\mathcal Z$.
A note on the Legendre transform
In thermodynamics, you often see that the canonical ensemble and grand canonical ensemble are related by a Legendre transform. Mathematically, setting the potentials:
$$
F = -T\ln Z \\
\Omega = -T\ln\mathcal Z
$$
then you have the conjugate variables $N$ and $\mu = T\ln z$ so that:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F}{\partial N} &= \mu & \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial \mu} &= -N \\
\Omega &= F-\mu N & F &= \Omega+\mu N
\end{align}
$$
In the context of statistical mechanics, this only holds for the thermodynamic limit, $N\to\infty$, which is always assumed in thermodynamics. What is exact is the $z$ transform. The canonical ensemble only defined for integer values, so the chemical potential is ill defined since you cannot take the derivative. You first need to smooth the function which is only well defined in the thermodynamic limit. It's the same caveat as between the microcanonical ensemble and the canonical ensemble.
Take the simplest example of a single orbital system of energy $0$ with no loss of generality (taking it as the origin of energy), with degeneracy $D$. In the canonical ensemble:
$$
F = -T\ln\binom DN
$$
and as expected, it is defined only for integer $N$, so you cannot even properly define $\mu$ and the Legendre transform.
In the grandcanonical ensemble, you rather have:
$$
\Omega = -TD\ln(1+e^{\beta\mu})\\
N = D\frac1{e^{-\beta\mu}+1}
$$
$N$ therefore takes continuous values so you can already see a discrepancy. Performing the Legendre transform, you find:
$$
\Omega+\mu N = TD\left[\left(\frac ND\right)\ln\left(\frac ND\right)+\left(1-\frac ND\right)\ln\left(1-\frac ND\right)\right]
$$
which rigorously disagrees with the canonical ensemble for finite $N,D$. Note however, that the two agree in the thermodynamic limit where $N\to\infty$ and $D/N$ converges to a finite value (i.e. $D$ is extensive), using Stirling's formula.
Hope this helps.

Even in conversion to the GCE, we still need to determine the fugacity. Don't we still need to determine fugacity, which depends on chemical potential?

In the GCE, fugacity $z$ is fixed. You can deduce from it chemical potential $\mu=T\ln z$. In this sense, fugacity and chemical potential are still well defined for discrete number of particles. I just meant that the differential definition from thermodynamics does not apply.

I think LPZ already gave a very good answer, so here I'll just add a comment and a general picture.
In some sense, you can say that this kind of problem is exactly one of the reasons you would like to consider a grand canonical ensemble in the first place. The canonical partition function is exactly what is explained there with the summation $(N_k)\in\{0,1\}^K$ but together with an annoying constraint $\sum_{k} N_k =N$. As far as I know, there is no simple way to write this down without the constraint in a consice sum.
You can view the grand canonical ensemble as a mathematical trick that Legendre transforms the particle numbers $N$ with the fugacity $z$, so that an intuitive simple summation without annoying contraints could be written down.

Thanks for the positive feedback. Your answer gives a good bird's eye view, but I have a small objection for your last paragraph though. The Legendre transform only holds when performing the saddle point on the partition function, or, more physically, the thermodynamic limit (technical caveat: the dual variable of $N$ is $\mu$ the chemical potential, not the fugacity $z$). For example, it does not work for the example linked in the question (2 orbital system).

@Jun_Gite17 Could you provide a few references that expand on your last paragraph?

Thanks @LPZ for your comment. You are right in that the dual variable for $N$ is not $z=e^{\beta\mu}$ but $\mu=\log(z)/\beta$. Sorry about this point; I was mixing them up because they're morally very similar. On the other hand, the Legendre transform picture should hold for a very broad range, even with two-level systems. For example, https://faculty.uca.edu/saddison/ThermalPhysics/GrandCan.pdf or https://itp.uni-frankfurt.de/~gros/Vorlesungen/TD/10_Grand_canonical_ensemble.pdf or any other standard explanation in GC can be a good reference explaining the transformation, >Alan

@Jun_Gitef17 Check out my addendum. It only works in the thermodynamic limit, for a finite number of levels, you'll need an extensive degeneracy.
